# WIX Forms on Item Page - Possible to pull in email from data field to submit form to?

Tags: forms, data, wix

I'm using the Wix Content Collections to store all the information for hair stylists working at a salon. I love how the item page function flows all the data from the collection to populate the photo, bio, phone number. However, I am running into difficulty with the contact form. I feel you should be able to send an email if a form is submitted on the person's item page you are on, but Wix support tells me this is not possible. So if someone wants to contact a stylist, I would like the 'submit' button to pull the correct email from the data associated with the stylist. Has anyone done something like this with custom java?
So it would be "if stylist selected = 'amy', then send submission to 'amy's email' located in this field of the data'

I would SO appreciate any help seeing if this is possible.

Comment: I ferl this is offtopic as its more about programming  than running a website